# Focusout in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

this code is not working when I `focusout` from year dropdown, nothing happens.
in class `.date-of-birth` there are `select` elements and where attribute `name` has value `DateOfBirthYear` is focused out. it should display the message

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.date-of-birth > select' ).attr('name','DateOfBirthYear').blur(function() { // also tried with .focusout()
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)
        var date = new Date(d);
        var dob = @Model.DateOfBirthMonth+"/"+@Model.DateOfBirthDay+"/"+@Model.DateOfBirthYear;
        var dateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
        if(dateOfBirth > d){
            $('.date-of-birth > .field-validation-error').text('Age cannot be in future');

        }
    });
});
```

Edit: my HTML is being created largely dynamically, so posting image from console
[image]

Comment: can you add some more information, its difficult to give an answer with so little information

Comment: I think you could add some more information, such as your HTML and make your explanation as to what you're looking to do a little clearer. But at first glance, it looks like you're using ASP.NET C# with Razor? Where you're defining `dob` you need some quotes around the `@Model.DateOf...` properties, otherwise JS won't see them as a string. And then you don't need to `+"/"+` them together. You can just do `var dob = '@(Model.Property1)/@(Model.Property2)/@(Model.Property3)';`. I don't think that's your ultimate problem, but I'm sure it will help a little :)

Comment: @AlessandroMinneci added html

Comment: @GeoffJames added snapshot of html

Comment: Might sound completely random, but can you try changing the listener: `.blur(function() { ...})` - to `.on('blur', function { ... })`. It's something to do with the way the `on("x")` hooks up differently to the `.blur()`. Not sure if this will make a difference. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.date-of-birth > select' ).attr('name','DateOfBirthYear').blur(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)
    var dob = @Model.DateOfBirthMonth+"/"+@Model.DateOfBirthDay+"/"+@Model.DateOfBirthYear;
    var dateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
    if(dateOfBirth.getTime() > d.getTime()){
        $('.date-of-birth > .field-validation-error').text('Age cannot be in future');

    }
});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of just posting code as an answer, it would be useful to explain what the issue might have been, and what steps can be taken to fix the issue, maybe an explanation of how your code works differently etc. It's not always clear to see straight away how a block of code will solve an OP's problem without some sort of explanation/annotation to boot :)

Comment: Sorry for that I though that diffs are obvious. 
dateOfBirth.getTime() > d.getTime()

Comment: No worries. To the trained eye it might be obvious, but I don't think there's any harm in adding a brief explanation You're not going to get slated for adding (even what may seem a somewhat meaningless) explanation to your answer - it might just help someone out who is less experienced or not as able to distinguish the change :)

Comment: Yep totally agree with you!

Comment: Can you just console out the dateOfBirth.getTime(), and d.getTime(), I assume that the problem is just in your date comparison?

Comment: nothing in console I wounder it is not going inside the block

Comment: I think the problem is in your blur(), this one in not reacting on your change, can you try to change blur() to change() and see if there is any console.log working